# Onload event not working in Dreamweaver browser preview

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

When I run an HTML file coded within Dreamweaver, my javascript function runs perfectly. But when the site is opened through Dreamweaver's Preview on Browser functionality it does not run.

This is an issue with the `onload="myFunction()"` event in the body tag. If I run the code by a button the function runs fine. It used to work fine but then one time when I opened Dreamweaver and previewed in the browser it stopped working. Using `window.onload function(){}` doesn't work either.

In the head I have this code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setCol() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
</script>
```

The function in actuality changes other elements with a randomiser but I don't think it should matter.

Then I have:

```html
<body onload="setCol()">
```

I want the function to run when the page is loaded, however, this doesn't happen when previewed through Dreamweaver. I get no error messages in the console `(ctrl + shift + j)`. It works perfectly when the HTML file is run by double-clicking or right-clicking and opening with chrome.

Comment: Check to make sure the script is before( in head tag) the body tag itself so that function is available when body is loaded.Quick test would be log setCol & see if is undefined -> <body onload="console.log(setCol)">

Comment: It is before it. Could it be an issue with the code though? I assumed since it works fine when just opened with chrome and not through Dreamweaver that it was some sort of config/preferences issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function {
        setCol();
    }, 100)
}
```

Then this will work i assume.

When the page is loaded it will wait 100 miliseconds then run the setCol(); function

You also have to remove the body onload function

Comment: This doesn't work either. Should've specified in original post, sorry, edited it to say this.